# rails before_destroy partial delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm trying to figure out a way to partially delete/destroy dependent models in rails.

Code looks something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :badges, :dependent => :destroy

  before_destroy :partial_destroy

  def partial_destroy
    self.photos.destroy_all
    self.badges.destroy_all
    return false if self.subscriptions.any? 
  end
...
```

Essentially, I want to destroy the photos and badges, but if the user has any subscriptions, I want to keep those, and also keep the user from being destroyed.

I tried with `.each { |obj| obj.destroy }` and using `delete` and `delete_all`, but it seems to not matter.

It looks like rails is performing some kind of a rollback whenever the `before_destroy` returns false. Is there a way to destroy part of the dependents but not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old so I expect you've forgotten it, but I stumbled across it.

I'm not surprised `delete` and `delete_all` didn't work, since those [bypass callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks).

You're exactly right that [Rails performs a rollback if any `before_` callback returns false](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#halting-execution). Because Rails wraps the entire callback chain in a transaction, you're not going to be able to perform database calls (like destroys) inside the chain. What I would recommend is putting a conditional in the callback:

- If the user has subscriptions, kick off a background job which will do this partial delete later (outside the callback transaction), and return false from the callback.
- If they don't have subscriptions, you don't start the background job, return true from the callback, and destroy your model as usual.

Comment: nice idea to use background jobs outside the normal flow! I did something similar within the flow, by overriding `destroy`. I ended up not actually deleting the object, but deleting most dependants and then nulling some fields (e.g. email). I should probably post it an an answer to give more info...

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but I think there is some sense in what I ended up doing as well. I'll let people make their own decision what solution they think is best, but at least I posted a [possible workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25580672/305019)

Comment: Agreed, there's certainly more than one way to do this. It's good to have multiple options; everyone's use case is slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up doing the following:

- override `destroy` on the `User` model (see below)
- not actually deleting the `User`, but rather destroying the dependants that are not needed, and blanking any fields on the `User` model itself, e.g. email.
- I created a `UserDeleter` class that takes the user and performs all clearing operations, just to keep things cleaner / having some kind of single-responsibility

### overriding `destroy`

```
  def destroy
    run_callbacks(:destroy) do
      UserDeleter.new(self).delete
    end
  end
```

### deleting dependants and clearing data on User

```
class UserDeleter

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def delete
    delete_photos
    delete_badges
    clear_personal_data
    # ...
  end

  private

  def delete_photos
    @user.photos.destroy_all
  end

  def clear_personal_data
    @user.update_attributes!(
      :email => deleted_email,
      :nickname => '<deleted>')
  end

  def deleted_email
    "deleted@#{random_string}.com"
  end

  def random_string(length = 20)
    SecureRandom.hex(length)[0..length]
  end
#...
end
```

Comment: I like this pattern. I don't think in terms of OO patterns enough so I wouldn't have thought of this.